# Сканнеры в программе

Tags: java

Сколько раз можно инициализировать сканер в одной программе?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cuple_functions_header {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        just_first();
    }

    private static void just_first() {
        Scanner go_chooze_function = new Scanner(System.in);
        String chooze_function =  go_chooze_function.nextLine();

         if(chooze_function.equalsIgnoreCase("random")){
             random_numbers();
         }
         if(chooze_function.equalsIgnoreCase("passvord")){
             password_function();
         }
    }

    private static void password_function() {
        //насколько правильно ещё раз  объявлять сканер?
        //возможно я должен воспользоваться другим способом  
        Scanner go_password_function = new Scanner(System.in);
        just_first();
    }

    private static void random_numbers() {
        just_first();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильно объявлять конкурирующие сканеры `System.in`. Это даже [описано на securecoding](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream). Проблема в том, что сканеры могут вычитывать ввод наперёд из входного потока, и значит, один из сканеров будет мешать другому, и есть хороший шанс, что будет прочитано в результате не то, что введено.

Например, представьте себе, что сканер читает число. Для этого он читает символы из входного потока, пока не встретит не-цифру. Эту самую прочитанную не-цифру он оставляет себе для следующего вызова. Если следующий вызов будет через другой сканер, этот экземпляр сканера ничего не знает об вычитанной из потока не-цифре, и просто не увидит её.

Лучше объявите статическую переменную, положите туда сканер, и инициализируйте в начале `main`.

Как-то так:

```
class cuple_functions_header {

    private static Scanner scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        just_first();
    }

    private static void just_first() {
        String chooze_function =  scanner.nextLine();

        if(chooze_function.equalsIgnoreCase("random")) {
            random_numbers();
        }
        if(chooze_function.equalsIgnoreCase("passvord")) {
            password_function();
        }
    }

    private static void password_function() {
        just_first();
    }

    private static void random_numbers() {
        just_first();
    }
}
```

Comment: я правильно понял? Добавит static  к String chooze_function =  go_chooze_function.nextLine();  ?

Comment: упс, не досмотрел, В НАЧАЛЕ main

Comment: @CoffeJava: Дописал примерный код.

Comment: @CoffeJava: И ещё дописал короткое объяснение причины.